# Name of this 4-pin fan connector

Tags: pwm, identification, connector, fan

I have a 40mm fan with a connector that has standard breadboard pin spacing. I would like to connect it to what I thought was a relatively standard fan connector that has wider spacing (and thicker pins).

In the image below, the fan is wired to the connector on top; I'd like to connect it to the connector on the bottom:

[image]

What is the name of the larger connector? That would make it easier to find an appropriate adapter.

Comment: Is the pitch 3.96 mm by any chance?

Comment: Seems like it could be, sure.

Comment: Or 5/32" (~0.156") pitch, for those wondering why the designer didn't just choose 4 mm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both: single-wall wire-to-board connectors. But ...

- Top: [CPU fan connector female plug](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=single_wall_conn_2p5&s=CPU%20fan). 2.54 mm pitch, unlatched, compatible with 3 and 4-circuit PCB headers. (my site)
- Bottom: [JST VH male PCB header](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=single_wall_conn_4_latch&s=VH%20(1w)): 3.96 mm pitch, latched. (my site)

Note: even if you have the [matching plug](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-4N/608626), that doesn't mean that it will work. We don't know whether the PCB male header is intended for a fan, and, if it is, what its pinout and signaling is.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great reference! We do know that the PCB male header is intended for a fan, and we also know the pinout of the connector matches the fan.